# C++ finding value of Pi

Tags: c++, oop

i'm new to c++ oop concept and trying to write a code that calculates value of pi with formula to given number, wrote the code below but getting error, any idea to fix it?

**Error**

error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and '')

**Header File**

```
using namespace std;


class Pi
{
public:
    Pi (const int nTerms);
        
    double apprErr();
    //uses value() function’s return and value of M_PI, returns approximation error.
    void print(){
        cout<<value<<endl;
        
    } // //uses value() function’s return displays it
private:
    int n;
    double value(); // return value of pi with assigned number of terms
};
```

**Pi.cpp**

```
Pi::Pi(const int nTerms){
        n=nTerms;
        
        double init=4;
        double initBottom=3;
        
        for(int x=0;x<n;x++){
            
            if(x%2==0){
                init-=(4/initBottom);
            }else{
                init+=(4/initBottom);
            }
            initBottom+=2;
        }
        
    };


int main(){
    Pi pi1(2);
}
```

Comment: `cout << value` `->` `cout << value()`.

Comment: Also the constructor doens't make sense. It does some calculation on local variables, but discards any results. Also you forgot to implement `Pi::value()`

Comment: understood what you're saying but really can't figure how to implement Pi::value() can you suggest any guide or explain a bit? Basically i need to assign return value of default constructor to value() variable

Comment: ***really can't figure how to implement Pi::value()*** That is a totally different problem. This problem / question you have asked was about the error message. It was already answered correctly so please don't attempt to change the question. Also if you do create a brand new question about how to implement `value()` you will most likely have to make an attempt to write the code for value. We don't usually give much help unless we see a good faith attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Your confusion is probably coming from trying to use a class for something it’s not suited for, namely executing a numerical algorithm. First implement `double approximatePi(int nTerms)` as a free function, and then decide if you need to pile any OOP on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

The line `cout<<value<<endl;` gives an error because `value` is a function pointer and `<<` doesn't know how to print a function pointer.

If you want to print the value a function returns, you have to call it, like `value()`

You didn't ask in your question, but there are implementation issues with your code as well.  How are you going to get the calculation in the constructor to value() ?  Why are you saving n?  Why are you not saving the calculated value?  Should the calculation be done in the constructor or in value() itself?

These are all design decisions with no single correct answer, so you need to think about it and make those decisions as part of writing the code.